# Why does this Bash pathname expansion not take place?

Tags: bash, pathname, variable-expansion

I'm struggling with Bash variable expansion. Please see the following code:

```
~/tmp 689$ a=~/Library/Application\ *; echo $a
/Users/foo/Library/Application *

~/tmp 690$ echo ~/Library/Application\ *
/Users/foo/Library/Application Scripts /Users/foo/Library/Application Support
```

As the order of expansion is brace->tilde->parameter->....->pathname, 
why is pathname expansion not applied to `$a` in the same way that it is in the 2nd command?

[added]

Does whitespace escaping have hidden behaviour regarding the following output?

```
~/tmp 705$ a=~/Library/Application*; echo $a
/Users/foo/Library/Application Scripts /Users/foo/Library/Application Support
```

Comment: Perhaps the un-quoted, un-escaped spaces you have in your paths on line 5?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem since line 5 is the output of line 4.

Comment: `~` expansion is special. Use `$HOME` there and it'll work.

Comment: It does not work, sadly: 694$ a=$HOME/Library/Application\ *; echo $a
/Users/foo/Library/Application *

695$ echo $HOME/Library/Application\ *
/Users/foo/Library/Application Scripts /Users/foo/Library/Application Support

Comment: @EtanReisner: `~` actually _is_ expanded when used unquoted in assignments; i.e., _tilde_ expansion _does_ take place, but _pathname_ expansion _doesn't_, and the latter is the problem. As a potentially interesting aside: unquoted `~` is not only expanded as the _first_ char., but also after [unquoted] `:` chars. (to help with defining `$PATH`-like variables); e.g. `a=~:~`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do what you meant to do, you'd have to use the following:

```
a=(~/Library/Application\ *)  # use an *array* to capture the pathname-expanded results
echo "${a[@]}"                # output all array elements (without further expansion)
```

---

As for why your code didn't work:

**In the context of variable *assignment* involving only *literals* or *string interpolation* (references to other variables), *NO pathname expansion* takes place, even with *unquoted* strings** (e.g., `a=*`, `a="*"`, and `a='*'` all assign *literal* `*`)<sup>[1]</sup>.

(By contrast, pathname expansion *is* applied to unquoted strings inside an *array* definition (e.g., `a=(*)`, or inside a *command substitution* (e..g, `a=$(echo *)`).)

Thus, the literal content of `$a` is `/Users/foo/Library/Application *`

Executing `echo $a` - i.e., NOT double-quoting the variable reference `$a` - then applies *word splitting* and does the following:

- it prints literal `'/Users/foo/Library/Application'` (the 1st word - no expansion applied, due to its contents)
- it prints the pathname expansion applied to `*` (the 2nd word - i.e., it expands to matching filenames in the *current* dir.)

The fact that the latter results in `*` in your case implies that you happen to be running the `echo` command from an *empty* directory (save for hidden files, assuming the default configuration).

---

<sup>[1]</sup>Whether the string is unquoted or not does, however, matter with respect to *tilde expansion*; e.g., `a=~` expands `~` to the user's home directory, whereas `a='~'` or `a="~"` assign *literal* `~`.

Comment: @cwyang: Glad to hear it. It's easy to get confused in these matters; understanding all the intricacies of shell string processing and expansions is no small feat.